# Как закинуть текст в центр изображения при табличной верстке?

Tags: html

Привет. Верстаю страницу для email рассылки. Есть код с картинкой:

```
<tr>
    <td align='center' style="color:#43525a; padding-top: 10px; padding-bottom: 10px;">
        <img src="img/line-2.png" alt="" title="" width="570px" height="28px" style="display:block;">
     </td>
</tr>
```

Вот так сейчас:
[image]

А нужно так:
[image: А нужно так:]

Реально ли такое?

Comment: это можно решать без картинки - через стили рамки. Но в вашей реализации попробуйте добавить text-align: center для ячейки

Comment: @AlexanderHalimon такие рамки я думаю не получится сделать через стили. Эти бордеры фирменные от заказчика.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
<tr>
    <td align='center' style="color:#43525a; padding-top: 10px; padding-bottom: 10px;">
        <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/foWze.png" alt="" title="" width="570px" height="28px" style="display:block;">
      <p style="width: 570px; position: relative; margin-top: -20px; text-align: center; font-size: 12px;">ОДЕЖДА</p>
     </td>
</tr>
```

Можно так.